# Need help with Factory and Dependency Injection

Tags: php, mysql, dependency-injection, pdo, factory-pattern

I'm trying to use [Dependency Injection](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Applying-the-Dependency-Injection-Pattern-and-Factory-Methods-in-PHP-5/1/) and [Factory](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/) class. I've read quite a bit about this and seen a lot of examples. But I don't think I'm using DI correctly (of Facotry class for that mater.

I'm not able to query my database. I get the error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Conn::query()`.

The problem is in the `getRows($sql)` function.

It seems I've not been able to use DI correctly and it's not able to use `PDO` functions.

Can someone point me in the right direction and maybe see what I'm doing wrong?

This is my code so far.

```
$user = Factory::createUser();
$result = $user->getUsers();
print_r($result);
```

And here are all the other classes:

```
class Factory {
  // I think I'm using Dependency Injection here
  function createUser($id = NULL) { return new User(new Conn(), $id); }
}

//Returns PDO conection and that's it.
class Conn {

  function config($cfg_file = 'sl.config') {   
    /* The code here returns $conf array */
  }

  function Conn() {
    $conf = $this->config();
    try { return new PDO($conf['dsn'], $conf['user'], $conf['pass']); } 
    catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }
    }  
}

interface iUser {
    public function getSomething();
}

// This is where I do all my SQL queries and return results.
class UserDAO {
  private $db = NULL;
  private $id;

  function UserDAO (&$db, &$id = NULL) {
    $this->db = &$db;
    $this->id = &$id;;
  }  

  public function getRows($sql)
  {
    $result = $this->db->query($sql); // <------- THIS IS NOT WORKING
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
    return $row;            
  }

  function getUsers($limit = 10) {
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $limit";
    return $this->getRows($sql);
  }
}


class User extends UserDAO implements iUser {

  public function getSomething() {
    echo "Something";
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to return an object in your `Conn` constructor, which just doesn't happen.  Constructors return `void`.  Add another method, like the `getDatabaseObject` method I've added below to return your `PDO` object.

```
class Conn {
    function Conn() {
        $conf = $this->config();
    }

    public function getDatabaseObject() {
        try { return new PDO($conf['dsn'], $conf['user'], $conf['pass']); } 
        catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }
    }
}

class Factory {
    // I think I'm using Dependency Injection here
    function createUser($id = NULL) {
        $c = new Conn();
        return new User($c->getDatabaseObject(), $id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing your User constructor a connection and an id

```
return new User(new Conn(), $id);
```

Since the User class doesnt have a constructor php fires the base class' constructor

```
function UserDAO (&$db, &$id = NULL) {
    $this->db = &$db;
    $this->id = &$id;;
  }
```

So essentially you are passing the UserDAO a connection object when it wants a db object

That's why its trying to run the `query` function on the `Conn` object

Comment: I kind of understand. What do I have to do to get the DB object? And should I use a `__constructor` on my UserDAO class?

Comment: @Steven, as you suggest you should be using a `__construct()` method as your constructor as it makes the constructor more obvious (it's easy to forget the name of the class and then not realise that it's a constructor) and it also means it's one less line of code to change if you change the class name in the future.